# Create Group in ASmack

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I'm newbie in asmack..
How do I create a group in a group tab in asmack?
I have tried `createGroup(String name)` as shown here [link](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/3.2.2/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/Roster.html)

but it seems that it is only makes a group in user tab.

Does anybody know how to make it?
Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear about your question but if you use createGroup(String groupName), you could try this way:

Roster.createGroup(groupName).addEntry(RosterEntry)

because when you create a roster group you have to add at least one entry(RosterEntry) to the group or it won't save. hope I answer your question